Neovim 10.1 and 11dev Exits Immediately with $qm
I'm trying out neovim for the first time, coming from vim. I'm trying to run it in an in an enterprise environment and neovim just exits immediately with a $qm that blinks out quickly in the top left corner. Is there something in my environment that might be causing this? I excluded neovim from Defender and ASRs, but that didn't fix it. Vim has no issues. Searches on this only returned 2 results. One was a bug report which supposedly had been fixed in dev, but I'm still impacted on the latest version, the other was quickly dismissed as off-topic.

Welcome to Vim! Could you tell us what is the OS you are running (Windows, Linux mac OS)? Do you have an init.vim or an init.lua and what is his content? How do you start Neovim (running the nvim command?)?

Oops, forgot the basics. Windows Server 2016/2019, base install no init.vim or init.lua, launching nvim from either cmd, powershell or gui produces the same result.

Ok, after further testing it appears this happens only on Server 2016 hosts, most likely due to the lack of ConPty support which nvim most likely depends on.
